# Post & Get method in one function? Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a function that needs to do a post and get action. 
I'm creating an offer system. Customers can ask an offer. This offer is called `$pendingOffer`. A worker can accept the offer and when it accepts the database row will transfer into the `$offer` table. The pendingOffer is still in the pendingOffer table. I want to delete this. I use POST method to store the pendingOffer into the Offer table. I want to use GET method to delete the pendingOffer. How do i do this?

Routes:

```
Route::post('/create_offer/{request}/{id}', 'RequestOfferController@saveCreateOffer');
```

My Controller:

```
public function saveCreateOffer(RequestOffer $request, RequestOffer $id) {
    $data = Request::all();

    $offer = new Offer($request->getAttributes());
    $offer->save();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['products']); $i++) {
        $productId = $data['products'][$i];
        $productCount = $data['count'][$i];
        $start = $data['date'][$i];
        $period = $data['per_periode'][$i];
        $btw = $data['btw'][$i];

        $product = Product::find($productId);
        if (!$product) {
            $offer->delete();
            return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['error' => 'Één van de producten kon niet gevonden worden.']);
        }

        $offerProduct = new OfferProduct();
        $offerProduct->product()->associate($product);
        $offerProduct->offer()->associate($offer);
        $offerProduct->count = $productCount;
        $offerProduct->start_date = Carbon::parse($start);
        $offerProduct->btw = $btw;
        $offerProduct->period = $period;
        $offerProduct->save();
    }

    $pendingOffer = RequestOffer::find($id);
    $pendingOffer->delete();

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

I've tried using the `::find($id)` method but this isn't working. I get this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:
```

Comment: Can you post your full controller (with the imports), and the full backtrace of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you combining them in one function/method if they are different request methods and perform different actions?  Create a new route and new controller method for each action.

You could have the same URL for a post and get in your routes file.

Ex:

```
Route::post('/create_offer/{request}/{id}', 'RequestOfferController@saveCreateOffer');
Route::get('/create_offer/{request}/{id}', 'RequestOfferController@deleteOffer');
```

Although, to me, it doesn't make sense to use a GET on this URL to delete the pending offer.  You should probably use a DELETE request to a more fitting URL to delete the offer.